# assign row name while rbind a row in a data frame

Tags: r, rbind

I want to assign a rowname (A_B) while I rbind a row into a new dataframe (d). 
The row is the result of the ratio of two rows of another data frame (df).

```
    df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B" ),replicate(3,sample(1:100,2,rep=TRUE)))
    d <- data.frame()
    d<-rbind(d, df[df$ID == "A",2:4 ]/df[df$ID == "B", 2:4])
```

Actual output

```
    X1   X2   X3
1 0.08 0.14 0.66
```

Expected output. Instead of rowname 1 I want A_B as result of A_B ratio

```
       X1   X2   X3
A_B 0.08 0.14 0.66
```

Comment: It is very unclear on what you are trying to get at. Your code throws an error, what is df ? where is that data ?

Comment: I tried to explain it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated the solution to address multiple rows**

You can workaround for the desired row names from following solution....

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B" ),replicate(3, sample(1:100,8,rep=TRUE)))
# This is where you control what you like to see as the row names    
rownames(df) <- make.names( paste("NAME", df[ ,"ID"]) , unique = TRUE)
d <- data.frame()
rbind(d, df[df$ID == "A",2:4 ]/df[df$ID == "B", 2:4], make.row.names = "T")
```

*output*

```
               X1        X2         X3
NAME.A   0.8690476 1.1851852 2.40909091
NAME.A.1 1.8181818 0.8095238 1.01408451
NAME.A.2 0.8235294 5.4444444 2.50000000
NAME.A.3 1.4821429 1.8139535 0.05617978
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of `make.row.names=T` is it possible to assign a rowname I choose such as NAME or A_B

Comment: I don't think you can choose but, you can control what you like to be displayed. However, as I mentioned earlier you would not be able to have duplicate row names in scenario where there are many rows. I assume, as you are working with dataframe you have multiple rows.

Comment: There won't be a duplicate row names, each row should have different name (A, B, C...). I want to calculate the ratio of different rows B/A, C/B, B/A and save the result in a new data frame that should report also the original row utilised to calculate the ratio

Comment: The solutions above assume that you are only dividing A/B. If you are trying to control 3 type of division and assign row names then it is a completely new approach. Update your Q, and I will see what I can do later.

Comment: Thanks, what I want to control is the names of my final dataframe  (d)

Comment: if you know which row belongs to respective calculation. The simple way would be `rownames (d) <- c("A_B","C_B","B_ A")`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's a stupid solution, but have you tried give it directly the row name? Some like this:

```
rbind(d, your_name = (df[df$ID == "A",2:4 ]/df[df$ID == "B", 2:4]))
```

For me it's working... Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign row names by passing your rbind output into a pipe to the function rownames() and mutate the row name as you like.

```
%>% rownames(.) <- c("Name you like")
```

Just make sure you mutate the correct row you intended.