# Setting row names and leaving some columns blank while appending to an `R` data.frame

Tags: r

I have looked through a number of Q&A on the topic of including `row name`'s as part of newly added rows to a data-frame - but have not had success in achieving that end.

The intention is to start with an empty `data.frame` with the desired columns specified  and be able to add named rows with the first three column values only (leaving the last column empty/optional):

The empty `data.frame`:

```
> df
[1] trun       YErr       lambda.min lambda.1se
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Let us add a row with name=`logr` and just the `trun` value set:

```
      trun       YErr       lambda.min lambda.1se
logr   2983      93211.89      0.2189
```

The motivation would be to access the row by name:

```
    df["logr"]
```

I have tried just *too many* options to achieve the above - and am *far* from a solution. One of the resources is this question: [assign row name while rbind a row in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982549/assign-row-name-while-rbind-a-row-in-a-data-frame).   Here is the (very poor) current attempt:

```
cols = c("trun","Yhat", "lambda.min","lambda.1se")
ncols = length(cols)
df = as.data.frame(setNames(replicate(ncols,numeric(0), simplify = F), cols))

df = rbind(df, "logr" = c(2983, 93211.89,  0.2189))
```

This does not set the `row.name` - and in fact it *overwrites* the column names as well ..

```
  X2983 X93211.89 X0.2189
1  2983  93211.89  0.2189
```

So .. then it's required  to do a completely separate call to set the `row.name` ??

```
row.names(df) = "logr"
> df
     X2983 X93211.89 X0.2189
logr  2983  93211.89  0.2189
```

The rows will be added to the `data.frame` *at various times in processing* .. so approaches that apply `row.names` *in bulk* will not work (not all the rows are necessarily available yet).

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `data.frame` type? To me a better solution is with `list()`, at least if I understood you correctly.

Comment: You can set each `list` element name with `names()`, and each element can be a simple `vector` or a `data.frame` made just by one row and p columns

Comment: The reason for a `data.frame` is to allow access to the data manipulation available to that structure at any time. Rows will be added much later in the processing - and I can not "wait" for *all* of them to be available before running analyses.  Is your suggestion leading to maybe appending `list` elements to the `data.frame`?  Will the row names be preserved in that fashion once inside the `data.frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to have already set the rowname in the `rbind` call:

```
df = rbind(df, data.frame(trun = 2983,
                          Yhat = 93211.89,
                          lambda.min =  0.2189,
                          lambda.1se = NA,
                          row.names = "logr")) 

> df["logr", ]
     trun     Yhat lambda.min lambda.1se
logr 2983 93211.89     0.2189         NA
```

To add a new line (per OPs follow-up):

```
df = rbind(df, data.frame(trun = 17,
                          Yhat = 18,
                          lambda.min =  19,
                          lambda.1se = NA,
                          row.names = "newline")) 

> df["newline", ]
        trun Yhat lambda.min lambda.1se
newline   17   18         19         NA
```

Note: This is highly inefficient in R, if at all possible pre-allocation of a `data.frame`and filling it in is much quicker, or even dynamically building a `data.frame`, but doing so every 10k rows or something like that.

Example:

```
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(trun = rep(NA, n),
                 Yhat = rep(NA, n),
                 lambda.min = rep(NA, n),
                 lambda.1se = rep(NA, n))

rownames(df)[1] <- "logr" # note you can use a counter here to keep track of row instead of `1`
df["logr", ] <- c(2983, 93211.89, 0.2189, NA)

> df["logr", ]
     trun     Yhat lambda.min lambda.1se
logr 2983 93211.89     0.2189         NA
> head(df)
     trun     Yhat lambda.min lambda.1se
logr 2983 93211.89     0.2189         NA
2      NA       NA         NA         NA
3      NA       NA         NA         NA
4      NA       NA         NA         NA
5      NA       NA         NA         NA
6      NA       NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Is this supporting the incremental additions of (newly named) rows to the existing `data.frame` ?  (Oh maybe it does - I see this appears to be  appending a row. will try it out.)

Comment: Follow up in post

Comment: I do *not* want highly inefficient  - though also do not need the *most* efficient.  Can you add the pre-allocation code - let's say I know there will be 1000 rows (but do not know the `row.names` in advance)

Comment: I am trying to avoid re-specifying the column names each time - along the lines of this:  `cols = c("algo","trun","Yhat", "lambda.min","lambda.1se");
df = rbind(df, data.frame(c("logr",2983, 93211.89,  0.2189,NA),col.names=cols,row.names="algo"))`  but that is giving an error `'row.names' should specify one of the variables`

Comment: Thx for adding the `rep` to make this more efficient.

Comment: I see that your update for the pre-allocation also will avoid needing to re-specify the column names each time.  I think this is an acceptable end result.