# rbind data frames in R, possible to add more than a number to duplicated rownames?

Tags: r, rbind

When using rbind in R to combine two data frames with an identical row name it adds "1" to the second row name.

```
df1 = data.frame(A=1:3,B=1:3)
df2 = data.frame(A=1:3,B=1:3)

rownames(df1) = c("A1","B1","C1")
rownames(df2) = c("C1","C2","C3")

rbind(df1,df2)

# A B
# A1  1 1
# B1  2 2
# C1  3 3
# C11 1 1
# C2  2 2
# C3  3 3
```

However, in my case the row names already contain letters with numbers (gene names), so adding an additional "1" change C from number 1 to number 11. Is there a way to force rbind to for instance add an additional dot or underline so "C1" becomes "C1.1" or "C1_1" instead of "C11"?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984551/10264278) has some tips that could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing important information in rownames you can have them in separate column. Use `make.unique` to have a unique name.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

res <- df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  bind_rows(df2 %>% rownames_to_column()) %>%
  mutate(rowname = make.unique(rowname, sep = '_'))

res

#  rowname A B
#1      A1 1 1
#2      B1 2 2
#3      C1 3 3
#4    C1_1 1 1
#5      C2 2 2
#6      C3 3 3
```

If you need the values back as rownames use `column_to_rownames`.

```
res %>% column_to_rownames()

#     A B
#A1   1 1
#B1   2 2
#C1   3 3
#C1_1 1 1
#C2   2 2
#C3   3 3
```

Comment: upvoted for the `make.unique`. never seen/used before.

Comment: Perfect solution. library(tibble) is also required for rownames_to_columns

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984551/10264278, you can create new rownames afterwards:

```
df1 = data.frame(A=1:3,B=1:3)
df2 = data.frame(A=1:3,B=1:3)

rownames(df1) = c("A1","B1","C1")
rownames(df2) = c("C1","C2","C3")

new_df <- rbind(df1,df2)

# create new row names
rownames(new_df) <- c(paste0(rownames(df1), "_df1"), paste0(rownames(df2), "_df2"))
```

Output:

```
> print(new_df)
       A B
A1_df1 1 1
B1_df1 2 2
C1_df1 3 3
C1_df2 1 1
C2_df2 2 2
C3_df2 3 3
```

You can improve it using `make.names()`, this function chec if each name is unique and if it does not contain "forbidden" characters.

```
make.names(c(paste0(rownames(df1), "_df1"), paste0(rownames(df2), "_df2")), unique = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# make list of df's
L <- list(df1, df2)
# set to data.tables, keep rownames in column 'rn'
L <- lapply(L, setDT, keep.rownames = TRUE)
# rowbind to data.table
DT <- rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE)
# temparary value id
DT[, id := rowid(rn)]
#create new rd, remove temporary column
DT[id > 1, rn := paste(rn, id - 1, sep = ".")][, id := NULL]
#      rn A B
# 1:   A1 1 1
# 2:   B1 2 2
# 3:   C1 3 3
# 4: C1.1 1 1
# 5:   C2 2 2
# 6:   C3 3 3
```